Can someone explain why I cannot swap_ranges between std::set and std::vector?
int t[] = { 210, 90, 8, 0, 52, 53, 23, 34, 91, 88 };
set<int> s1(t, t + 10);
vector<int> v1(s1.rbegin(), s1.rend());
swap_ranges(s1.begin(), s1.end(), v1.begin());  // error here

I've looked through various C++ STL websites and can't make heads or tails of it.
